# Given $(\mathbb R,\tau)$, show that $(a,b)$ is open in $(\mathbb R,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{(a, b] : a, b ∈ \mathbb R, a < b\}$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb R$ and that such topology is not the Euclidean one. I need to show that each interval $(x, y)$ is open in $(\mathbb R, \tau)$. But this seems curious to me, because if $(x,y)$ is open, then it is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$ and I'd not know how to write every $(x,y)$ in this way. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $(x,y)$ as the union of basic open sets:
$$(x,y) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (x, y - 1/n]$$
and therefore $(x,y)$ is open for $\tau$ (taking the convention that $(x, y-1/n] = \varnothing$ if $y - 1/n < x$, to deal with the case $y < x-1$).

In particular this shows that if a set is open for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, then it is open for $\tau$ (the converse isn't true).

Comment: Great! Thank you for your solicitude! I'd suggest changing $n=0$ to $n=1$ in union, but it is fine.

Comment: @shn woops${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

If $x<y$, then there is $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $y- \frac{1}{m}>x$. Let $I_n=(x,y- \frac{1}{n}]$ for $n \ge m$. Then

$(x,y)=\bigcup_{n \ge m}I_n$

Comment: Enlightening and elegant! Thank you! :)